# How to get only syntax errors in redshift from java?

Tags: java, mysql, postgresql

I am using Amazon Redshift as my database. When I am making a database call using Java, if there is syntax error in given query, it throws

> exception":"class org.postgresql.util.PSQLException

But this exception is not only for syntax errors. I get this exception if there is a connection timed out and permissions denied for user and etc.

For Example:
QUERY 1: `select foo from foobar`

> Exception and Message are as follows: {"exception":"class
>   org.postgresql.util.PSQLException","message":"ERROR: column \"foo\"
>   does not exist in foobar"}

QUERY2: `select from foobar` (missed the *)

> Exception: {"exception":"class
>   org.postgresql.util.PSQLException","message":"ERROR: syntax error at
>   or near \"from\"\n  Position: 80"}

How can I use the exception and find that it is because of SQL syntax? 
because I need to display it to the user that if he enters a query with wrong syntax.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the SQL State value in the exception:

```
try {
    // code that fails
} catch (PSQLException e) {
    if (PSQLState.SYNTAX_ERROR.getState().equals(e.getSQLState())) {
        // handle syntax error
    } else }
        // handle other error
    }
}
```

See the javadoc of [PSQLState](https://jdbc.postgresql.org/development/privateapi/org/postgresql/util/PSQLState.html) for full list of well-defined SQL State values.

Comment: Thank you very much for the help. I printed out the catch block if statement parameters and i got the follwong System.out.println("error code 1"+p.getSQLState()); -->42703(undefined_column)
            System.out.println("error code 2"+PSQLState.SYNTAX_ERROR.getState()); --> 42601 (syntax_error) . I just tried the QUERY 1 from the above question. So even though it has a syntax error, its not going into the if loop as there is no match in the states

Comment: There are a bunch of error codes for different syntax errors. I am not able to figure out just to get the syntax one's . For example                                            42P19 invalid_recursion
42830 invalid_foreign_key
42602 invalid_name
42622 name_too_long
42939 reserved_name
42804 datatype_mismatch
42P18 indeterminate_datatype
42P21 collation_mismatch
42P22 indeterminate_collation
42809 wrong_object_type
42703 undefined_column
42883 undefined_function

Comment: "Undefined column" is not a *syntax* error. Adding the column to the table would fix it, without changing the SQL statement. Your definition of "syntax error" is very lax, so maybe you should look at it from the other side. Which errors are not "syntax errors"? Treat everything else as a "syntax error".

Comment: I am considering that as a syntax error as sometime the user enters a column name which is not in the table and it throws a syntax exception. But in order to display him the error message and let him know that the column name you entered is not in the table, I am trying that case as well. Considering other scenarios, there are a lot of error codes for different kind sql errors even though all are sql syntax errors.

Comment: As I said, they are *not* **SYNTAX** errors. `UNDEFINED_COLUMN` means the SQL statement is *syntactically* correct, but the table doesn't have a column by that name. `NUMERIC_VALUE_OUT_OF_RANGE`, `DATA_TYPE_MISMATCH`, and `DATETIME_OVERFLOW` means that the value doesn't fit that columns datatype, but the SQL statement itself is valid. And so on... Why not just show the error itself? It says what is wrong.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help Andreas. Ya you are right. Sorry for not adding this in my question. For now I am  sending a status 500 to the UI and displaying error message to the user as you said.My new requirement is instead of sending status 500 for syntax errors, i need to send status 200 for SYNTAX ERRORS and for any other errors i need to send status 500. That is the reason i need to get only syntax errors.